# ASP.Net C# MVC Group domain model and place results into ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework

I want to select certain fields from my domain model, and group by a field within the domain model, and put the results into a ViewModel - however, I can't get the Linq syntax correct.

My Model is:

```
public class Offer
{
    public int OfferId { get; set; }
    public string Inclusions { get; set; }
    public string Property { get; set; }
    public bool IncludeInOffer { get; set; }
    public Guid guid { get; set; }
    public int NumPeople { get; set; }
    public int NumNights { get; set; }
    public DateTime ArrivalDate { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public DateTime OfferCreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string OfferReference { get; set; }

     }
```

My ViewModel is:

```
 public class OfferVMList
{
    public string guid { get; set; }
    public int NumPeople { get; set; }
    public int NumNights { get; set; }
    public DateTime ArrivalDate { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public DateTime OfferCreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string OfferReference { get; set; }
}
```

My Linq is:

```
 OfferVMList item = db.Offers
        .GroupBy(x => x.OfferReference)
        .Select(ct => new OfferVMList
        {
            NumPeople = ct.NumPeople           
        })
        .OrderBy(x => x.ArrivalDate);
```

However, the error message is:

`System.Linq.IGrouping<string,FGBS.Models.Offer>' does not contain a definition for 'NumPeople' and no extension method 'NumPeople' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IGrouping<string,FGBS.Models.Offer>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`'

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong please?

Thank you

Comment: its because the `ct` is actually a list of things rather than a single entity

Comment: ok thanks - so how do I get the results from db.Offers, grouped and into the ViewModel?

Comment: Your view model is not adapted. A group means that you have a collection of keys (by `OfferReference` in your case) and for each key you have a collection of `Offer`. So how can this possibly fit with your `OfferVMList` model?

Comment: you should also use implicit declarations not explicit, so `var` instead of `OfferVMList`

Answer (score 3):

Check this:

```
var item = db.Offers
        .OrderBy(x => x.ArrivalDate);
        .GroupBy(x => x.OfferReference)
        .Select(ct => ct.Select(x => new OfferVMList {
            NumPeople = x.NumPeople
        });
```

Comment: `NumPeople` is an integer. `ct.Select` returns `IEnumerable<int>`.

Comment: Thanks - but that gives the error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>' to 'int'

Comment: You did not include the group by ?

Comment: @YD1m : Can you explain in the post about the need of inner Select Statement ?

Comment: @PKKG: `ct` is a *list* not a single entity, so if you want to convert each item in the list into an instance of `OfferVMList` you need to do another select.